# Windows authentication(NTLM) in a silverlight application "Out of browser"

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis, authentication, out-of-browser

I've a web application, which works without any problem in my browser. But if I install it out-of-browser, when I try to get the username, the userAccount isn't in the dictionary:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
  string userId = e.InitParams["UserAccount"];//--> KeyNotFoundException
  //...
}
```

Which is normal because I give it through the launch of silverlight in the aspx web page:

```
<param name="InitParams" value="UserAccount=<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>" />.
```

I need it because sometimes in my application, I need to display the current logged user, and display that it's this user which will do this or this action before I save it.

So, one question:

- How to manage to ensure that the user has the right to load the application AND retrieve the userId.

Thank you very much!

J4N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it seems it isn't possible, I've to create a WCF service which return the current logged user.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it client-sided like this:

```
e.InitParams["UserAccount"] = Environment.UserName;
```

This only gets the username though but does exactly the same as the other example you displayed.

However, it is never a good idea to set permissions based on a username provided by the client (which both this and your example does).

Comment: Are you sure? Because I can't find any "UserName" property on my Environement var

Comment: I'm not sure that this is readeable with silverlight. And for your previous concern: I don't set any permission on that, it's the server which is responsible for that, but some times I need to display the current user, or display only objects relatives to the current object, but it's only ergonomics concerns, never security.